# Point an internal IP address to an external URL

Tags: router, home-networking, port-forwarding, nat

Is it possible to set a router up so a machine in the LAN can access an Internet URL using an internal IP address?

I have a cheap DVR box that can save recorded videos to a FTP server, but only supports fixed IP addresses. Since IP adresses may change from time to time, I'd like to map an internal IP address to an external FTP server using the FTP server URL.

Comment: Google "reverse proxy"